# rpm installation using puppet

Tags: puppet

I am new to Puppet - I have been playing around learning the basics. Most of the examples ( except the very basic ones )  that are on the [puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/#learning-puppet) page do not work for me - either some dependency is missing or package is not found. I do not see the logs explaining what went wrong ( even if I run the --test or --verbose option)

Can anyone clarify

1 What is the simplest process ( set of simple steps ) for installing a rpm package on a single Linux box ?

2 In general - how does one go about using the modules on the forge.puppetlabs ? Are the providers for these packages installed automatically or they have to be manually installed first ?

Answer (score 1):

To install a package named `pacman` from command line:

```
puppet resource package pacman ensure=present
```

Corresponding puppet code will look like:

```
package { 'pacman':
  ensure => '4.0.3-5',
}
```

Explore for more options about the package resource [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#package)

Regarding the question of installing puppet modules, have a look [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/modules_installing.html). Official doc is your friend :)

Personally, I just copy-paste the module directory manually in a git repo which I use to maintain my puppet code.

Comment: I get this when i try your instruction : err: /Package[pacman]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Could not find package pacman  - This error itself makes sense to me - what I find somewhat confusing is how Puppet claims that it will install these packages - the details are missing - where does puppet find the installer - where is the repo and how will it proceed to actually install the package -?

Comment: Add `--debug --verbose` to see the command puppet is executing and try running that same command without the options that make it quiet to see what's wrong.